# A Lithium Like Minecraft Block in 1.19.2

Tags: java, minecraft-forge, forge

Im trying to create a mod with a block that acts like lithium when exposed to water... i already have so the block breaks when placed in water but now im trying to do so the block disappears from the players inventory if the player touches water, the reason why i cant get it to work is because im new to the minecraft forge modding industry so i mostly use ChatGPT (i know its bad but i dont know what else to do) but the porblem is that ChatGPT has a cutoff date where 1.19.2 wasnt introduced yet.

Ive tried making PlayerTickEventHandler's and BlockItems but i just cant get it to work, its pretty annoying since ive used alot of time wasted on something that doesent work. Anyways im in forge 1.19.2, Windows PC, and using IntelliJ IDEA (i dont know if thats relevant), so i joined StackOverflow to try and improve my mod and future mods i plan to make.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Can you precise where you are stuck like do you have logs, issue or something? Can you show your code and explain what's you want?

Comment: We can't help you without code. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)